# Track campaigns in Google Analytics, without changes to URLs and query parameters, and without modifying web pages

Tags: parameters, google-analytics, query-string

Say that I have visitors to my site coming from a campaign, the URL contains the parameter `?xxx=123` to indicate this campaign.

All documentation I found for tracking campaigns with GA tells me to use the `utm_campaign` etc querystring parameters. However, I am not always able to modify the URLs that are used in campaigns.

One solution I found, was using some JavaScript in my webpages to rewrite the incoming URL into something that uses `utm_campaign`. However, I also don't want to modify my website for every campaign.

I am not able to find any documentation on how to simply use a custom URL parameter in GA to track a campaign. Is that not possible? It seems to me a very reasonable usage case...

Answer (score 0):

Push `_setCampNameKey` between `_setAccount` and `_trackPageview` like this:

`_gaq.push(['_setCampNameKey', 'xxx']);`

Here's Googles Documentation:

_setCampNameKey Docs (function): https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCampNameKey

Custom Tracking Docs (use case): https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCampaigns#customCampaignTracking

Comment: That requires me to change (the JavaScript on) my webpages for every new campaign, right? I really prefer not to do that, isn't there a solution just by doing things in GA?

Comment: It's only a single change assuming you keep "xxx" the same. It's a key/value pair.  "key" should always be something like "source" and then the value should be the campaign name.  If you only ever have one querystring value, you could always break it up in the code and _setCampNameKey programatically with a variable.